# NA handling with write.fwf in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am trying to convert matrix data based on code like below for numerical simulation.
However, I would like to save the NA values so that there is no space, but I have no idea.
Could someone please tell me?

```
library(gdata)

a <- matrix(c(1 : 6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
a[a == 6] <- NA

write.fwf(a, paste0("test.txt"), colnames = F, width = 17, justify = "right", na = "")
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to write instead of a space?

Comment: @user2554330 I hope there's nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you clarified that you don't want to output anything for `NA` values.  In that case, you aren't writing a fixed width format (because you want width 17 for most values, but width 0 for NA), so you shouldn't be using `write.fwf()`.  Just format the values, paste them together, and write the lines.

For example:

```r
a <- matrix(c(1 : 6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
a[a == 6] <- NA

formatted <- format(a, width = 17)
formatted[grepl("NA", formatted)] <- ""

lines <- apply(formatted, 1, paste0, collapse="")
writeLines(lines, "test.txt")
lines
#> [1] "                1                3                5"
#> [2] "                2                4"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>